# how to replace word automatically in excel

Tags: excel

In one sheet i have this data

A   APPLE

B   BANANA

C   CROW

D   DEER

E   EGG

F   FISH

G   GOAT

H   HUT

In another sheet whenever i write A in a column, apple should be written in the next column.

A (i write A) then Apple should be written in the column next to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to use VBA Script in Excel.  Starting with an example in [Worksheet.Change Event (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change), you could use the following code to achieve your goal.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 1 Then
        ThisRow = Target.Row
        If Target.Value = "" Then
            Range("B" & ThisRow).Value = ""
            Range("B" & ThisRow).Show
        End If

        If Target.Value = "A" Then
            Range("B" & ThisRow).Value = "Apple"
            Range("B" & ThisRow).Show
        End If
        If Target.Value = "B" Then
            Range("B" & ThisRow).Value = "Banana"
            Range("B" & ThisRow).Show
        End If
        If Target.Value = "C" Then
            Range("B" & ThisRow).Value = "Crow"
            Range("B" & ThisRow).Show
        End If
        If Target.Value = "D" Then
            Range("B" & ThisRow).Value = "Deer"
            Range("B" & ThisRow).Show
        End If
        If Target.Value = "E" Then
            Range("B" & ThisRow).Value = "Egg"
            Range("B" & ThisRow).Show
        End If
        If Target.Value = "F" Then
            Range("B" & ThisRow).Value = "Fish"
            Range("B" & ThisRow).Show
        End If
        If Target.Value = "G" Then
            Range("B" & ThisRow).Value = "Goat"
            Range("B" & ThisRow).Show
        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

---

Writing 'A' in column A and row 1, you need to move off that cell to trigger the `Worksheet_Change` event and you should see `Apple` appear in column B on the same row.